# InfoPath. System Account issue

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that I am publishing to a Central Admin and then uploading that form as a content type in a form library. When I am filling a new form,it is showing form Modified By "System Account",where else if I am creating a document library and then uploading some document to it,is is showing Modified By user, I want to get rid of this System Account thing, so that I can create a view where user will be able to see the forms created by them only. How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you accessing the forms library with a different account? When you create a new form (from your content type) the user creating the form should be in the "modified by" field.

Comment: It should, but it does not, unfortunately. I have found the same issue with an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointinfopath/thread/82654c84-e231-48d2-88cd-daefd768a649? but it does sound like a workaround and is not 100% clear where should I do it. Should I use IteamAdding event receiver or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems like I have found what was wrong:

1. When I reproduced the issue I logged in to my virtual machine with the SharePoint and InfoPath as system administrator. Then in IE I logged in as a member and pushed new document button. The InfoPath saves my form under System Account permissions. It sounds like the error.
2. After that, I have tried to log in to the virtual machine as a member and then created a new InfoPath form. In this case the InfoPath has saved my form under the member permissions.

The conclusion is: when InfoPath saves a form, it uses your account which you were logged in under and ignores an account set in SharePoint.